# Pivot table refresh and save code in aspose cells for java corrupts excel file

Tags: java, aspose-cells

I am using aspose-cells-8.7.2-java. When I refresh the pivot table and save it, the excel file is getting corrupted. When I try to open the excel file I am getting the alert message as below :

```
"Excel found unreadable content in 'Book1.xlsx'.Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook?If you trust the source file of this workbook, click yes."
```

The code is as below :

```
Workbook wb = new Workbook("Book1.xlsx");
PivotTable pt = wb.getWorksheets().get(1).getPivotTables().get(0);
pt.refreshData();
pt.calculateData();
wb.save("Book1.xlsx");
```

Any help ?

I found this thread where the same issue is logged as a ticket :
http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/683715/aspose.cells-generates-a-corrupted-xlsx-file-excel-2007-fails-to-open.aspx.
Is this issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the logged issue is not resolved yet. By the way, do you use similar Excel file or yours template file "Book1.xlsx" is different. Moreover, your issue can be template specific (if you are using different file) and might have different scenarios, so we need your template "Book1.xlsx" file to properly evaluate your issue on our end. We recommend you to kindly create a separate thread in Aspose.Cells [forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.cells-product-family/19/showforum.aspx) with your template Excel file, we will evaluate your issue and help you better there.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: Has this been fixed yet? I'm thinking about trying Aspose.Cells for. NET

Comment: No, I am afraid, it is not resolved yet. You should follow up the Aspose forum thread for latest updates/info.

Comment: Oh, now I see this is a Java question; is it also a problem in .NET?

Comment: Yes, original issue was posted in .NET Aspose.Cells APIs. Generally, once an issue is fixed in .NET version, it will be fixed in relevant JAVA version. I suggest you to kindly post your issue in a separate thread with your resource files, we can help you better there.

Comment: I don't have that issue, I was just researching whether I should put my eggs in the Aspose basket.

Comment: Well, you should. The issue is more specific to template file (containing Pivot Table/charts) provided by that user. Generally, Aspose.Cells does not display such an issue and it works fine with Excel files.